# check header response and unset 404 returns url

Tags: php

I have 2 urls. [0] returns 404, [1] returns 301. trying to unset url that gives 404.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "http://www.myricacity.com//outline"
  [1]=>
  string(50) "http://www.cigr.co.jp/pj/shinchiku/A80297//outline"
}

function response($url){
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $httpcode;
    }
```

But when I try to unset.

```
foreach($redirects as $k => $val){
    if ((response($val) == 404)) {
        if (!in_array($val, $dumpLinks)) {
            $dumpLinks [] = $redirects[$k];
            unset($redirects[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

I do `var_dump` `$redirects` but still contains both values.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what do you mean? If you were to do a `var_dump($redirects);` after the `foreach()` loop, would it not contain the right values?

Comment: I mean when I `var_dump` `$redirects` still contains both values. @dearsina

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, which only leads me to believe that there is something up with your `response()` function: https://3v4l.org/uUTBr

Comment: I gave the real links, question updated. could you try it again?  @dearsina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working as intended, try the following `foreach()` to get a better idea of what's going on:

```
foreach($redirects as $k => $val){

    $httpcode = response($val);
    //Break it out...
    echo "{$redirects[$k]} returned {$httpcode}\r\n";
    //...so that you can see what you're getting

    if ($httpcode == 404) {
        if (!in_array($val, $dumpLinks)) {
            $dumpLinks [] = $redirects[$k];
            unset($redirects[$k]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($redirects);exit;
```

**Expected output**

```
http://www.myricacity.com//outline returned 404
http://www.cigr.co.jp/pj/shinchiku/A80297//outline returned 301
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(50) "http://www.cigr.co.jp/pj/shinchiku/A80297//outline"
}
```